# Model Binding not working with mvc1

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We have very large object called FoodFormViewModel. We go to add page like

```
FoodFormViewModel foodFormViewModel = new FoodFormViewModel();
return View("Edit", foodFormViewModel);
```

But when we come to post method like

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Edit(FoodFormViewModel objViewModel)
{
    SaveProcess(objViewModel);
    return View(objViewModel);
}
```

Our objViewModel properties are all blank. Our FoodFormViewModel definition is

```
#region Properties

public MealPlannerDataManager MPManager { get; set; }

public Food Food { get; set; }

public SelectList FoodGroupLevel1 { get; set; }
public SelectList FoodGroupLevel2 { get; set; }
public SelectList FoodGroupLevel3 { get; set; }
public SelectList FoodType { get; set; }
public SelectList Company { get; set; }
public SelectList Brand { get; set; }
public SelectList NutritionSource { get; set; }
public SelectList DataSource { get; set; }
public SelectList PlannerSource { get; set; }
public SelectList PublishMonth { get; set; }
public SelectList PublishDay { get; set; }
public SelectList PublishYear { get; set; }
public SelectList TagTypes { get; set; }

public List<CheckBoxInfo> MealTime { get; set; }
public List<CheckBoxInfo> Condition { get; set; }
public List<CheckBoxInfo> Allergens { get; set; }
public List<CheckBoxInfo> Occasions { get; set; }
public List<CheckBoxInfo> Others { get; set; }
public List<CheckBoxInfo> SpecialDiet { get; set; }
public List<CheckBoxInfo> Course { get; set; }
public List<CheckBoxInfo> PrepMethod { get; set; }
public List<CheckBoxInfo> Season { get; set; }
public List<CheckBoxInfo> SkillLevel { get; set; }
public List<CheckBoxInfo> Cuisine { get; set; }
public List<CheckBoxInfo> MealPlan { get; set; }
public List<CheckBoxInfo> Products { get; set; }
public List<CheckBoxInfo> AgeGroup { get; set; }

public FoodNutritionInfo NutrInfo { get; set; }
public FoodNutritionInfo AltNutrInfo { get; set; }

Tag dummyTag = new Tag();
TagType dummyTagType = new TagType();
#endregion Properties
```

WE couldn't figure out the issue. Any help is highly appreciated.
We are using MVC1 with VS 2008

My view contains 3-4 partial views, i am posting one of the partial view here

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MealPlannerAdmin.Models.ViewModel.FoodFormViewModel>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="MealPlannerAdmin.Models.Objects.HTMLHelpers" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="MealPlanner.BusinessObjects.Model" %>
<div id="ValidationSummary" style="position: absolute; margin: 110px 0px 0px 620px;
    width: 350px; height: 359px; overflow: auto; border: 0px">
    <%=Html.ValidationSummary("Please review all tabs for following errors") %>
</div>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div id="foobar" style="color: Red;">
                    <%=ViewData["CloningMessage"]%></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="comHead">
                <strong>Food Basic Information</strong>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div id="divCloningMessage" class="errMsg">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div id="divBtnCloneThisFood" style="display: none;">
                    <input type="button" value="Clone this Food" id="btnCloneThisFood" name="btnCloneThisFood" />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="200" valign="top">
                <span id="spanOriginalCreatorLabel"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="spanOriginalCreator"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="200" valign="top">
                <span id="spanClonedByLabel"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="spanClonedBy"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="200" valign="top">
                <label for="lblFoodID">
                    Food ID:
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="spanFoodID" name="spanFoodID">
                    <%=Model.Food.FoodID%></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="ddlFoodGroupLevel1">
                    Food Group Level 1: *</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%=Html.DropDownList("ddlFoodGroupLevel1", Model.FoodGroupLevel1, new { @class = "dropdown"})%>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%=Html.ValidationMessage("FoodGroupLevel1", "*")%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="ddlFoodGroupLevel2">
                    Food Group Level 2 :
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%=Html.DropDownList("ddlFoodGroupLevel2", Model.FoodGroupLevel2, new { @class = "dropdown" })%>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%=Html.ValidationMessage("FoodGroupLevel2", "*")%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="ddlFoodGroupLevel3">
                    Food Group Level 3:
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%=Html.DropDownList("ddlFoodGroupLevel3", Model.FoodGroupLevel3, new { @class = "dropdown" })%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="Food.FoodName">
                    Food Name: *</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%=Html.TextBox("FoodName", Model.Food.FoodName, new { @maxlength = "250" })%>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%=Html.ValidationMessage("FoodName", "*")%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="FoodDisplayName">
                    Food Display Name: *</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%=Html.TextBox("FoodDisplayName", Model.Food.FoodDisplayName, new { @maxlength = "250" })%>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%=Html.ValidationMessage("FoodDisplayName", "*")%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="ddlFoodType">
                    Food Type: *</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%=Html.DropDownList("ddlFoodType", Model.FoodType, new { @class = "dropdown" })%>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%=Html.ValidationMessage("FoodType", "*")%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="rowCompany">
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="ddlCompany">
                    <span id="spanCompany" name="spanCompany"></span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%=Html.DropDownList("ddlCompany", Model.Company, new { @class = "dropdown" })%>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%=Html.ValidationMessage("Company", "*")%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="rowAddCompany">
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" valign="top" class="subHead">
                            <label for="txtAddCompany">
                                <span id="spanAddCompany" name="spanAddCompany"></span>
                            </label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <%=Html.TextBox("txtAddCompany", string.Empty, new { @id = "txtAddCompany", @maxlength = 100, @boundButton = "btnNewCompany", @catId = Convert.ToInt16(EntityConstants.TagType.Company), @catName = EntityConstants.TagType.Company, @updateEle = "divAgeGroup", @uiUpdateType = "drop-down-list" })%>
                            <div id="divAddCompanyError" boundbutton="btnNewCompany" class="errHidden">
                            </div>
                            <div id="<%=EntityConstants.TagType.Company %>Message" style="display: none; color: Red;">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <%=Html.TextArea("txtAddCompanyDesc", string.Empty, 5, 42, new { @id = "txtAddCompanyDesc", @class = "text-area-classic w374px", @boundButton = "btnNewCompany" })%>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="bottom">
                            <input type="button" value="Add" id="btnNewCompany" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="cblMealTime">
                    Meal Time:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <%=Html.CheckBoxGrid("cblMealTime", Model.MealTime, 4) %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%=Html.ValidationMessage("Meal", "*")%>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="ddlNutritionSource">
                    Nutrition Source: *</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%=Html.DropDownList("ddlNutritionSource", Model.NutritionSource, new { @class = "dropdown" })%>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%=Html.ValidationMessage("NutritionSource", "*")%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="ddlDataSource">
                    Data Source: *</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%=Html.DropDownList("ddlDataSource", Model.DataSource, new { @class = "dropdown" })%>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%=Html.ValidationMessage("DataSource", "*")%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="Display">
                    Display: *</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%=Html.RadioButton("Display", true, Model.Food.Display, new { @id = "DisplayTrue" })%><label>Yes</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <%=Html.RadioButton("Display", false, !(Model.Food.Display), new { @id = "DisplayFalse" }) %><label>No</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="Issue">
                    Issue: *</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%=Html.RadioButton("Issue", true, Model.Food.Issue, new {@id="IssueTrue", @onclick= "disableIssueText()"})%><label>Yes</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <%=Html.RadioButton("Issue", false, !(Model.Food.Issue), new {@id="IssueFalse", @onclick = "disableIssueText()" })%><label>No</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="IssueDescription">
                    Describe Issue:
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%=Html.TextArea("IssueDescription", Model.Food.IssueDescription, 4, 75, new { @maxlength = "50", @class = "w500px" })%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="FoodDescription">
                    Description:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%=Html.TextArea("FoodDescription", Model.Food.FoodDescription, 5, 40, new { @maxlength = "50" })%>&nbsp;<%=Html.ValidationMessage("FoodDescription", "*")%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="Tags">
                    Tags:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%=Html.TextArea("Tags", Model.Food.Tags, 5, 40, new { @maxlength = "50" })%>&nbsp;<%=Html.ValidationMessage("Tags", "*")%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="Image">
                    Image:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <%=Html.Image("Img200x200", Model.Food.Img200x200, "Food Image", new { @width = "200", @height = "200" })%>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div id="browseFile">
                                <input name="Image" id="Image" type="file" size="45" onchange="document.getElementById('inputTxtFake').value = this.value;"
                                    class="inputImage" />
                                <!-- fake input to display the path of the selected file : start -->
                                <input name="inputTxtFake" type="text" id="inputTxtFake" />
                                <!-- fake input to display the path of the selected file : end -->
                            </div>
                            <input id="ClonedFromFoodID" name="ClonedFromFoodID" type="hidden" value="<%=Model.Food.ClonedFromFoodID %>" />
                            <input id="IsUserFood" name="IsUserFood" type="hidden" value="<%=Model.Food.IsUserFood %>" />
                            <input id="Img200x200" name="Img200x200" type="hidden" value="<%=Model.Food.Img200x200 %>" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var isUserFood = '<%=Model.Food.IsUserFood %>';
        var hasClones = '<%=Model.Food.HasClones %>';
        var isClone = '<%=Model.Food.IsClone %>';
        var canClone = window.location.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf("/edit") > -1;
        var gettingCloned = window.location.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf("/clone") > -1

        if (hasClones.toLowerCase() == 'true') {
            $("#divCloningMessage").html("This food has already been cloned.");
            canClone = 'false';
        }

        originalCreator = '<%=Model.Food.OriginalCreator%>';
        clonedFromFoodID = '<%=Model.Food.ClonedFromFoodID%>';
        $("#spanOriginalCreatorLabel").html("Original Creator:");
        $("#spanOriginalCreator").html(originalCreator);

        if (isClone.toLowerCase() == 'true') {
            var originalCreator;


            $("#spanClonedByLabel").html("Cloned By:");
            $("#spanClonedBy").html("WFM Nutritionist");

            $("#divCloningMessage").html("This food is cloned from food with id " + clonedFromFoodID + ".");
            canClone = 'false';
        }

        if (canClone == true) {
            utility.ui.makeYUIButton("btnCloneThisFood");

            $("#btnCloneThisFood-button").click(function() {
                var cloneFoodId = '<%=Model.Food.FoodID %>';
                var clonedFoodUrl = '<%=Url.Content("~/") %>foods/clone/' + cloneFoodId;
                window.location = clonedFoodUrl;
            });

            $("#divBtnCloneThisFood").show();
        }

        var clonedFromFoodID = $("#ClonedFromFoodID").val();

        if (gettingCloned) {
            $("#spanFoodID").html("0");
        }

        utility.ui.makeYUIButton("btnNewCompany");

        checkForBasicFood();

        $("#ddlFoodType").change(function() {
            checkForBasicFood();
        });

        $("#btnNewCompany").click(function() {

            var btnID, txtNameId, txtDescId, catId, catName, eleToUpdateId, uiUpdateType;
            btnID = "btnNewCompany";
            txtNameId = $("input[boundbutton='" + btnID + "']").attr('id');
            txtDescId = $("textarea[boundbutton='" + btnID + "']").attr('id');

            catId = $("input[boundbutton='" + btnID + "']").attr('catId');
            eleToUpdateId = $("input[boundbutton='" + btnID + "']").attr('updateEle');
            catName = $("input[boundbutton='" + btnID + "']").attr('catName');
            uiUpdate = $("input[boundbutton='" + btnID + "']").attr('uiUpdateType');

            if ($("#" + txtNameId).val() == "")
                $("div[boundButton='" + btnID + "']").fadeIn().fadeOut(10000);
            else {
                var subCategory = {
                    categoryId: catId,
                    parentCategoryId: $("#ddlFoodType").val(),
                    categoryLevel: 2,
                    categoryName: $("#" + txtNameId).val(),
                    categoryDescription: $("#" + txtDescId).val(),
                    categoryIconPath: "",
                    sortOrder: 0
                };

                // Initializing food helper
                foodHelper.init('<%= Url.Content("~/") %>');

                foodHelper.addSubCategory(subCategory, {
                    updateElementId: eleToUpdateId,
                    updateDropdownID: "ddlCompany",
                    categoryName: catName,
                    messageDivId: catName + "Message",
                    catNameTxtBoxId: txtNameId,
                    catDescTxtBoxId: txtDescId,
                    uiUpdateType: uiUpdate
                });
            }
        });
    });

    function checkForBasicFood() {
        if ($("#ddlFoodType").val() == 1444 || $("#ddlFoodType").val() == -1) { // Bad: hard coding value

            $("#rowCompany").hide();
            $("#rowAddCompany").hide();
        }
        else {
            var selectedFoodType = $("#ddlFoodType").val();
            if (selectedFoodType == 688) {
                $("#spanCompany").html("Restaurant Brand:");
                $("#spanAddCompany").html("Add a New Restaurant Brand:");
                $("#divAddCompanyError").html("Please enter name for Restaurant Brand.");
            }
            else if (selectedFoodType == 689) {
                $("#spanCompany").html("Store Brand:");
                $("#spanAddCompany").html("Add a New Store Brand:");
                $("#divAddCompanyError").html("Please enter name for Store Brand.");
            }

            $("#rowCompany").show();
            $("#rowAddCompany").show();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure you surrounded your form with `<form>` tags? Did you use the HtmlHelpers, or write your own HTML?

Comment: Does the FoodFormViewModel type have a default constructor? How about the FoodNutritionInfo, MealPlannerDataManager and Food types? Are all the properties on the other classes used by FoodFormViewModel read/write?

Comment: Yes, FoodFormViewModel have default constructor. Also all other class used by FoodFormViewModel have their own constructor

Comment: alright, after editing this view code, I find it very hard for us to solve this, the view is huge and there's JS code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certain property name don't match with actual names............need to modify

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I think it is very odd to have properties of type `SelectList` and `List<CheckBoxInfo>` in your view model class. Most viewmodels should contain properties of very basic types, like `string` and `int`. The way you have, makes it very hard to debug & identify your problems but I would go and say that most likely the default model binder doesn't know how to bind values from HTML controls to your viewmodel props.

I would advise looking into building a custom modelbinder or rewriting the view model class. Or rewriting the app as a whole (but I guess that's not an option).

HTH